# Socket.io transport close and ping timeout error

Tags: socket.io

Socket client is getting disconnected either due to **transport close** or **pingtimeout** error. And it happens randomly. Sometime the socket client is stable for couple of hours and after that is start disconnecting randomly.Can anyone help me finding the issue.

**Socket-Client version** : 2.1.0 
  **Socket Server version** : 2.1.0,

**Client Code**

```
const socket = require('socket.io-client')
let url = 'http://localhost:5050'
let clientSocket = socket.connect(url, {
  reconnection: true,
  forceNew: true,
  secure: true
})
 clientSocket.on("connect", function (data) {
  // console.log(clientSocket)
  console.log("connection established");
 });
 clientSocket.on("event", function(data) {
  console.log(data)
})
```

**Server Code**

```
const socketio = require('socket.io');      
this.io = socketio.listen(this.server, 
{ 
    'pingInterval': PING_INTERVAL, 
    'pingTimeout': PING_TIMEOUT 
});
this.io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // const consumer = new ConsumerGroup(options, topic);
    // reading data from add event and sending back the same data
    console.log('Connected', socket.id);
    const token = socket.handshake.query.token;
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log(socket.id + ' -> Disconnected');
    });

    consumer.on('ready', function (message) {
        console.log('Ready');
    });
    consumer.on('message', function (message) {
        // sending message on socket when we recieve the message from kafka\
        socket.emit('alarm', message);
    });

    consumer.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('error', err);
    });

});
```

Comment: did u find any solution and fix to your problem? i m having same issue

Comment: @Faizan After digging around, the client was receiving a huge number of messages. Client will only disconnect when it was unable to cope up with the number of messages. Due to this unstable behavior we had to remove the sockets and shift our system to some messaging queue. (Kafak, Rabbitmq etc).